# How to Get GMT by using Google Time Zone API

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-timezone

I want to retrieve GMT(5.5) of India or same like this for other Country. Below is my code where I used Google Time Zone API and the coming response is on dstoffset, rawOffset, status, timeZoneId, timeZoneName. My question is how to get GMT (5.5) Thank you

```
 final String registerURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=30.293461,78.524094&timestamp=1331161200&key=API_KEY";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, registerURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        String s1 = obj.getString("dstOffset");
                        String s2 = obj.getString("rawOffset");
                        String s3 = obj.getString("status");
                        String s4 = obj.getString("timeZoneId");
                        String s5 = obj.getString("timeZoneName");
                        TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone(s4);
                        TimeZone tz2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone(s4);
                        tvTimeZone.setText(String.valueOf(tz2));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                        }
                    }
            );

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Please edit your question with what problem you are having as `rawOffset` is documented: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro#Responses

Comment: Actually sir, I want to get GMT(5.5) of India, how can I get that please suggest.

Comment: Since `rawOffset` is in seconds, what is wrong with dividing that amount by 3600 seconds (the number of seconds in a hour) to get UTC hours? And UTC is the same as GMT.

Comment: Okay I got it, Thank you Sir.

Comment: I also checked for Asia/Kabul where  "rawOffset" : 16200 and divide it from 3600 the result is 4.5 but the GMT of Asia/Kabul is 4.30.

Comment: Watch carefully, GMT of Asia/Kabul is not `4.30`, it is `4:30`. The result of the division, i.e. `4.5` is in hour and in a fraction number. That means it is `4.5 hours` which means that 4 and a half hour, which means that `4:30 hours`

Comment: Okay thanku @RakibulIslam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `rawOffset` is the offset from UTC (in seconds) for the given location.

As UTC and GMT has no time difference between them, dividing `rawOffset` by 3600 you can get the GMT time of your requested time zone.

And obviously, when divided by 3600, the answer is in fractions of hour not in the `hour:min` pair. So, if you get the output, say, `4.50`, that is actually `4.5 hours` which is the same as `4:30 hours (4 hours 30 minutes)`.

Comment: It is correct, If *dstOffset* is equal to zero, 
But, if *dstOffset* is not equal to zero , need to add *dstOffset* with *rawOffset*